How to copy from a html table without the top newline?
The code for my page is roughly as follows


<body style="margin-left:20px;">
    <table><tbody>
        <tr><td>456789</td><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body>



I often copy part of the prefix of the first row and column from it. In this case it's "4567".
And then paste into my terminal(zsh or bash shell) and run a  command that takes the prefix as a parameter.
As you know, the new line is treated as a new command.
I move my mouse to the left margin of the 4(This detail is very important for reproduction, is to move the mouse to the left side of the 4 about 10p. Therefore contains the margin-left of the <body>.), hold down the left button, and drag to stop at the 7 and press ctrl+C.
But what I copy comes out with a carriage return at the top.
I will get "\n4567" exactly.
How can I get "4567"?
This operation can be reproduced in website <textarea> , not limited to the terminal.
Test environment

Ubuntu 24.04 with Chrome 124.0.6367 incognito mode
Ubuntu 24.04 with Edge 120.0.2210 incognito mode
Windows 10 with Edge 120.0.2210 incognito mode

I don't have this problem with Firefox.
What is the elegant operation? I can only solve it in a very strange way so far.


<body style="user-select:none;">
    <table style="padding-left:20px;user-select:text;"><tbody>
        <tr><td>456789</td><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body>




I cannot reproduce this (Arch linux, i3 wm, st terminal, Firefox). When I copy 4567, this is what I have in the clipboard, no newline. I can echo "<ctrl+shift+v>" in the terminal.

@HeikoJakubzik I've edited and added chrome tags

Cannot reproduce with Chrome (124.0.6367.91), either -- sorry not to have more productive feedback to offer :-/. But I'm getting no newline with Chrome, either.

it could be one of your extensions. turn them off or use incognito mode to test
